# Every group of order $n$ with $p|n$ have a sub group of index $p$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Every group of order $n$ with $p|n$ have a sub group of index $p$, where $p$ is a prime number.

I think the above statement is false. Can anyone give me a counterexample or am I wrong?

Comment: I think you're confusing with Cauchy's lemma : the group has a subgroup of *order* $p$.

Answer (score 8):

Indeed this is false : for instance the alternating group $A_5$ has even order $n=60$ but doesn't have a subgroup of index $2$, because a subgroup of index $2$ is always normal, and $A_5$ is simple.

On the other hand, if $p|n$, there is a subgroup of *order* $p$.